# selenium WebDriver UrlChecker$TimeoutException, opens the browser and then never navigating to the link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, url, exception

I started learning Selenium on java the other day but I can't reach the link that I want, I'm using Opera the program starts by opening the opera driver then throwing an exception after few seconds and never navigating to the website that I want, I want to go to that web site and click the register button

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera/launcher.exe");

        WebDriver webDriver = new OperaDriver();
        webDriver.get("https://nemexia.2axion.com/?s=horus");

        try {
            webDriver.findElement(By.id("btn-register")).click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver.<init>(OperaDriver.java:173)
    at org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver.<init>(OperaDriver.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver.<init>(OperaDriver.java:115)
    at NormalClass.main(NormalClass.java:9)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:23877/status] to be available after 20004 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Are you using Maven project or Simple Java Project?

Comment: i'm using a java project a simple one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code for me it is working fine check the below image with a latest operadriver version 86.0.4240.80
[image]

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver","D:/operadriver_win32/launcher.exe");
    WebDriver webDriver = new OperaDriver();
    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    webDriver.get("https://nemexia.2axion.com/?s=horus");

    try {
        webDriver.findElement(By.id("btn-register")).click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
Test execution is working fine and it clicked on the button "Register Now"
```

[image]

Can you use the latest version of the operadriver 86.0.4240.80 and Opera browser
version 72.0.3815.400 can resolve your issue. Also check the operadriver.exe path

Answer (score 1):

I used selenium for python and had a similar problem when using
driver = Webdriver.Firefox()
The problem was that the program couldnt find the path of the searching machine of the browser and it did not work. I solved it by either add the path in the bracket of Webdriver.Firefox("path here") or copy the engine, incase of firefox it was geckodriver, inside the folder where the script is.
Another possibility is, that the site or the browser is just slow, and therefore you get that error. Also make sure that the link is 100% correct
If nothing helps, maybe think about choosing another browser, which is a bit more common like firefox or chrome

Not sure if this helps, but those are my experiences and i hope it somehow helps